# Convex combination of $2^n$ vectors from cartesian products of half-spaces

Tags: combinatorics, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

The following sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are defined:
$$
H_1 :=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \vert\ x_1\geq0\right\}\\
H_2 :=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \vert\ x_2\geq0\right\}\\
E_1 :=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \vert\ x_1=0\right\}\\
E_2 :=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \vert\ x_2=0\right\}\\
H_{12} :=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \vert\ x_1,x_2\geq0\right\}
$$
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let there be a given vector $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ from each of the $2^n$ different n-fold cartesian products of $H_1$ and $H_2$:
$$
\lambda_1 \in H_1\times H_1\times H_1\times\dots\times H_1\\
\lambda_2 \in H_2\times H_1\times H_1\times\dots\times H_1\\
\lambda_3 \in H_1\times H_2\times H_1\times\dots\times H_1\\
\lambda_4 \in H_2\times H_2\times H_1\times\dots\times H_1\\
\vdots\\
\lambda_{2^n} \in H_2\times H_2\times H_2\times\dots\times H_2
$$
**Claim:** There exists a $\lambda\in conv(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda)$ with
$$
\lambda\in\left(E_1\cup E_2\cup H_{12}\right)\times\dots\times\left(E_1\cup E_2\cup H_{12}\right).
$$
*Proof idea:*
Using the [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) one gets a vector $\varphi_j\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ from each of the $3^n$ different n-fold cartesian products of $E_1$, $E_2$ and $H_{12}$:
$$
\varphi_1\in E_1\times E_1\times E_1\times\dots\times E_1\\
\varphi_2\in E_2\times E_1\times E_1\times\dots\times E_1\\
\varphi_3\in H_{12}\times E_1\times E_1\times\dots\times E_1\\
\varphi_4\in E_1\times E_2\times E_1\times\dots\times E_1\\
\varphi_5\in E_2\times E_2\times E_1\times\dots\times E_1\\
\varphi_6\in H_{12}\times E_2\times E_1\times\dots\times E_1\\
\vdots\\
\varphi_{3^n}\in H_{12}\times H_{12}\times H_{12}\times\dots\times H_{12}
$$
If there is a vector $\lambda\in conv(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda)$ and a $\varphi_j$ ($j\in\{1,\dots,3^n\}$) with $\varphi_j^\intercal\lambda\geq0$, then the claim follows.

Comment: It should be $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is correct since $\lambda_i$ is contained in a n-fold cartesian product of sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Oh right I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an important "wlog" step. By compactness we can pick $\hat{\lambda_1},\dots,\hat{\lambda_{2^n}}\in\mathrm{conv}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{2^n})$ satisfying the same conditions about being in Cartesian products of $H_1$ and $H_2,$ but minimizing the volume of the convex hull $\mathrm{conv(\hat{\lambda_1},\dots,\hat\lambda_{2^n}}),$ and then minimizing the number of $i$ such that $\lambda_i$ is an extreme point of this convex hull: if the volumes are the same, we prefer a choice with fewer $\lambda_i$ at vertices. The convex hull of the $\hat{\lambda_i}$ is a subset of the convex hull of the $\lambda_i,$ so we can assume that $\lambda_i=\hat{\lambda_i}.$

One of the $\lambda_i$ is an extreme point of the convex hull of $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{2^n}.$ Let's assume it's $\lambda_1.$ I claim that $\lambda_1\in(E_1\cup H_{12})^n.$ It is enough to show $((\lambda_1)_1,(\lambda_1)_2)\in E_1\cup H_{12}$ because the other co-ordinates can be handled symmetrically. Let $a=((\lambda_1)_1,(\lambda_1)_2)$ and $b=((\lambda_2)_1,(\lambda_2)_2),$ so $a\in H_1$ and $b\in H_2.$ (For handling other co-ordinates we would need to use a different $\lambda_i$ than $\lambda_2.$) Either $a_1=0$ or $a_1>0.$ In the first case we're done: $a\in E_1.$ In the second case there exists $0<\theta<1$ with $a_1\theta+b_1(1-\theta)\geq 0$ (for example $\theta=|b_1|/(a_1+|b_1|)$). Define $\lambda_1'=\lambda_1\theta+\lambda_2(1-\theta).$ Note that $\lambda_1'\in H_1^n,$ and either $\mathrm{conv}(\lambda_1',\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_{2^n})$ has smaller volume (because $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_i$ for $i\neq 1$), or $\lambda_1'$ is not extreme in this new convex hull. By the minimality assumptions in the previous paragraph we get $\lambda_1=\lambda_1'.$ So $a=b\in H_{12}.$ In either case $a\in E_1\cup H_{12}$ as required.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant proof!
Which volume function is minimized in the first argument?
My guess is the Hausdorff measure in the smallest dimension $d\in\{0,1,\dots,2n\}$ with $H^d\left(conv\left(\hat{\lambda}_1,\dots,\hat{\lambda_{2^n}}\right)\right)<\infty$ for some $\hat{\lambda}_i$. Is there an easier way?

Comment: @Ricardo306: I'd missed that the $2n$-dim volume could be zero, but that's a good fix - first minimize the dimension $d$ of the convex hull, then minimize the $d$-dimensional volume.

Comment: An alternative you might like is that by Zorn's lemma we can take an inclusion-minimal compact convex set $S$ such that there exist $\hat{\lambda_1},\dots,\hat{\lambda_{2^n}}\in S$ satisfying the $H_i$ conditions. This needs the fact that the intersection of a chain of compact convex sets is a compact convex set, and that the conditions $x_1\geq 0$ etc give closed sets.

Comment: The dual form of this is that we can express the conditions on $\{\hat{\lambda_i}\}$ as linear inequalities and add a maximal set of conditions of the form $\phi\cdot \hat{\lambda_1},\dots,\phi\cdot\hat{\lambda_{2^n}}\geq c$ with $\phi\in\mathbb R^{2n}$ and $c\in\mathbb R,$ such that finite combinations of these conditions are satisfiable. Then by Helley's theorem they are all satisfiable, so there are $\{\hat{\lambda_i}\}$ that are minimal in a suitable sense.